# Avago 3108: rebuild degraded hardware RAID5?

Tags: hardware-raid, raid5, lsi, failed

Supermicro TwinPro chassis with dual SYS-1029TP-DC1R server modules, each with Supermicro X11DPT-PS motherboard and Avago 3108 RAID card.

OS: VMware ESXi 6.7.

Problem: can't figure out how rebuild an existing RAID5 array after a "failed" drive was replaced. (Not really failed; rather, it's an attempt to replace spinning disks with SSDs one-by-one, rebuilding the RAID group every time - as opposed to rebuilding the RAID group from scratch.)

- The "failed" drive: Seagate 7E2000 1TB mechanical drive (ST1000NX0303), 4K sector size
- The replacement one: Micron 5400 Max SSD 1.92TB (Micron_5400MTFD), 512B sector size

(Is it possible this RAID controller can't mix drives with different sector sizes in the same volume aka "virtual drive"?)

Notes:

- The controller is configured to start rebuilding on its own if a hot spare is available, or if a "UG" (unconfigured good) drive is inserted. (No rebuilding was happening in this case.)
- Setting the replacement drive as a "global hot spare" - no change, no rebuilding in progress, no "rebuild the array" option anywhere in the UI.

Thanks for any ideas!

[image: Avago MegaRAID 3108 BIOS]
[image: Avago MegaRAID 3108 BIOS]
[image: Avago MegaRAID 3108 BIOS]
[image: Avago MegaRAID 3108 BIOS]
[image: Avago MegaRAID 3108 BIOS]

(There are more screenshots available of various UI parts.)

Comment: It is almost certainly the controller can't mix different sector sizes, but also in LSI controllers there is a knob which enables the mix of HDD and SSD in the same array. It is obvious it needs to be "enabled" in your case. Also, I vote to close this as this doesn't show a reasonable management practice; if you are managing RAID in a business environment it's reasonable to have a stock of replacement drives (cold spares) as well as hot spares connected to the backplane; *all of same kind*.

Comment: we do have stacks of spare drives of the same kind; it would be a good practice before voting for closing anything or implying poor management practices to check if the situation allows for hot spares (it doesn't, not with only 4 available drive slots). This particular question and problem were a direct result of a sanctioned experiment where the existing spinning disks would be replaced one-by-one with SSDs; the host in question was taken offline (put in "maintenance" before performing any actions described above). I vote to qualify your comment and voting action as a moderation overreach. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure that's what it is - yet suspect the lack of "rebuild" option, and the reason the RAID5 volume doesn't start a rebuild on its own, is that an existing volume with 4Kn drives (4K sector size) can't take drives with a different sector size (512B). Wish the UI would do a better job indicating that.

What happened next:

- The moment I put the original drive back in, it got marked as "UB" ("Unconfirmed Bad")
- I then marked it "Unconfirmed Good" via "PD Mgmt" UI.
- The drive immediately became "foreign".
- I then "imported foreign configuration" in "VD Mgmt" UI.
- The drive then became a member of the original volume / drive group, and the volume started rebuilding. It's currently at 15% after about 20 minutes. The LED is solid red and the blue LEDs on all drives are blinking.

(I'll mark my own answer as the "solution" for now - yet if there comes a long a better answer, will be happy to switch to it as *the* answer.)